# how to use Aspose.word insert the mergefield and save into memeory steam

Tags: vb.net, aspose.words

I have a project need to merge the text into merge fields in words 2010 using Aspose.words. I know to do the merge. After merge,  I want to create it as filestream then save it to memeorystream then I will open it into the page and the user can choose save it or just open like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following overload of **Save** method to send the merged document to client browser.

```
doc.Save(Response, "Report Out.doc", ContentDisposition.Inline, null);
```

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            document.Save(stream, SaveFormat.Docx);
            var str = stream.ToArray();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(str);
            FileStream file = new FileStream("your path", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            ms.WriteTo(file);
```

Here you go buddy, just close the file and memory stream. You will be having the stream, which you asked for.